# facebook app suddenly shows ssl error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I am building a facebook app.  I don't have https. But It was working well before few minutes. But now when I try to access the app as https://apps.facebook.com/reelreview/ it shows an  SSL error as

```
Secure Connection Failed







      An error occurred during a connection to www.synergiadigital.com.
```

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
  Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem. Alternatively, use the command found in the help menu to report this broken site.

I know it is due to the lack of https, but my doubt is that it was working well before few minutes. And also was working well for the last few days. Suddenly it shows the error.

I am not able to find the exact reason and solution,

Please help me ,

Sincerely,

Sunil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your Account Settings -> Security -> Secure Browsing? Maybe by mistake you've changed it to "Browse Facebook on a secure connection"?

Comment: sometimes you are not start you server (wamp server) it may also cause .

Answer (score 0):

*This is not directly an answer to your question which is about an app - but answering anyway, since this is one of the top hits on google for the error message.*

The error can be caused when a plain HTTP response is being received on an HTTPS (SSL) connection.   The site is configured for HSTS, so a browser which has accessed the site previously will upgrade from http: to https: even before making an initial connection there, without a redirect.

In my case, Firefox gave *Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG* when the parental controls on the TP-Link household router was blocking the site, sending a "site blocked" response page on http: despite the connection being https:

[image: Firefox SSL error]

This was reveled using another browser which had not been used before (MS Edge), which did not know about the HSTS setting (it had never visited facebook.com before) and therefore followed the redirect back to the router parental controls error page showing a more user-friendly message:
[image: Edge Parental controls]